# Appending to array in foreach tcsh

Tags: arrays, shell, foreach, append, tcsh

I'm trying to make `foreach`iterate on all elements in the given array, considering that new elements might be appended to the end of the array.

```
foreach header ($list)
   set temp = `~/exercises/ex4/getheaders $header`
   set list = ($list `~/exercises/ex4/setdiff $temp -d $list`)
end
```

What happens actually is the *foreach* runs on the first `$list` it gets... and even when it grows the `foreach` does not "know" that.

I was wondering how can I make it "notice" the changes and keep on iterating the new elements...?

Comment: I know that sir, but that's not what I want.

I want to iterate over the new elements too.

Answer (score 2):

What probably happens, is that `foreach` gets the length of the list once (when first encountered), and caches that length for the duration of the loop. I didn't check the code, but this is the sane way to do it.

You can easily simulate the `foreach` behaviour with a `while` loop, here the length of the list (`$#list`) is retrieved for every iteration of the loop; and thus the loop will keep going until it stops growing.

An example would be:

```
set list = (I eat poop)
set original_length = $#list
set i = 1
while ( $#list >= $i )
    echo "$i -> $list[$i]"

    if ( $i <= $original_length ) then
        set list = ( $list "NEW$i" )
    endif
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Which should give the output:

```
1 -> I
2 -> eat
3 -> poop
4 -> NEW1
5 -> NEW2
6 -> NEW3
```

Note that this example assumes that you only want to "grow" the list for every original item; you could of course remove this condition, or change it, I don't know what behaviour you want (just be careful not to loop forever).